# How to put multiple values inside option and process it in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have a select element which is used to search for data from database, so for option data1 it will query data of data1 from database, option data2 will query data of data2 and so on, but I want an option where it can query all of the data in the select element. I am thinking of putting multiple values in an option and process it, I tried using array inside value and JSON method(which I haven't really understand), but I still couldn't think of the way to achieve this.

html :

```
<select name='select'>
    <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
    <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
    ...10++ more option
    <!--I want an option to select all with all the values, something like this, <option value='option1','option2','option3','option4','option5'...>Select all</option>-->
</select>
```

php :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
$option = $_POST['select'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE data='$option'";

//What I need is something like this when a user choose the option to select all:
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE data='$option1' OR data='$option2' OR data='$option3' OR data='$option4 and so on"

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this is not the only select, I have 30+ similar select element with different values but to access the same column in mysql database. As for now I put the value 'select all' for the select all option and I am using the switch method like this :

php switch:

```
<?php
switch($option) {
    case 'select all':
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE data='option1' OR data='option2' OR data='option3' OR data='option4' and so on..";
    break;
default:
    break;
}
?>
```

But I don't think this is the best method, as I have another 30++ select and I have to write each select case in the switch function and I don't this is clean.
Please teach me how to simplify this. Thx in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a `WHERE` clause in the SQL at all, if the intention is not to filter anything?

Comment: I am filtering option 1 to 10 where as in my data there is the data of option 1 to 100 which I have option 11 to option 20 in another select element, option 21 to option 30 in another select element and so on..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use This Code]

What you do is make one connect.php, where u write the code for db connection. u should not write in each and every page..
after that, use this code.. thank u